# Computing pairwise bitwise OR in a list of bit-strings

Tags: performance, programming-challenge, lisp, clojure, bitwise

I am trying to solve this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/acm-icpc-team) using Clojure:

> You are given a list of \$N\$ people who are attending ACM-ICPC World
>   Finals. Each of them are either well versed in a topic or they are
>   not. Find out the maximum number of topics a 2-person team can know.
>   And also find out how many teams can know that maximum number of
>   topics.
>
> Input Format:
>
> The first line contains two integers \$N\$ and \$M\$ separated by a single
>   space, where \$N\$ represents the number of people, and M represents the
>   number of topics. \$N\$ lines follow. Each line contains a binary string
>   of length \$M\$. In this string, 1 indicates that the ith person knows a
>   particular topic, and 0 indicates that the ith person does not know
>   the topic.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> On the first line, print the maximum number of topics a 2-people team
>   can know.  On the second line, print the number of 2-person teams that
>   can know the maximum number of topics.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$2 ≤ N ≤ 500\$
>
> \$1 ≤ M ≤ 500\$
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> ```
> 4 5
>
> 10101 
>
> 11100 
>
> 11010 
>
> 00101
> ```
>
> **Sample Output:**
>
> ```
> 5 
>
> 2
> ```

However, my implementation is too slow to pass all the test cases. What are some suggestions to optimize this implementation? Basically, I have a list of bit-strings, and I am trying to find a faster way to bitwise-OR every pair of strings, and find the maximum number of set bits that could be obtained from ORing a pair.

```
(let [[N _] (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")
      N (Integer/parseInt N)
      strings (vec (repeatedly N read-line))
      known 
      (for [i (range N) j (range (inc i) N)
            :let [s1 (strings i)
                  s2 (strings j)]]
        (apply + (map #(if (or (= %1 \1)
                               (= %2 \1))
                         1
                         0)
                      s1
                      s2)))
      maximum (apply max known)]
  (println maximum)
  (println (count (filterv #(= % maximum) known))))
```

Comment: Please revise the title to state the challenge, not the review request.  It would also help to embed the challenge objective.

Comment: "Finding the maximum bitwise union of pairs from a list of integers" is one possibility for a title that describes the challenge.  Also, there's a [tag:bitwise] tag that would be appropriate for this question.  And consider tagging as [tag:lisp] so that more people can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it accepted by optimizing the inner loop by using BitSets instead of plain strings. I then just used the BitSet's or and bit counting method (cardinality) to do the work. Here's the resulting code:

```
(import [java.util BitSet])

(defn string->bitset [str]
  (let [bitset (BitSet. (count str))]
    (doall (map-indexed #(when (= \1 %2)
                           (.set bitset %1)) str))
    bitset))

(defn bitset-or [s1 s2]
  (let [tmp (.clone s1)]
    (.or tmp s2)
    tmp))

(let [[N _] (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")
      N (Integer/parseInt N)
      bitsets (mapv #(string->bitset %) (repeatedly N read-line))
      known 
      (for [i (range N) j (range (inc i) N)
            :let [s1 (bitsets i)
                  s2 (bitsets j)]]
        (.cardinality (bitset-or s1 s2)))
      maximum (apply max known)]
  (println maximum)
  (println (count (filterv #(= % maximum) known))))
```

Answer (score 0):

One optimization would be to first build a map of the attendees with the number of topics for each one and find the maximum number of topics for a single person.  You know that the maximum number for a pair will obvious be larger than the maximum for a single person.  So when you loop over the pairs to compute the numbers of topics covered by a pair,  you can skip the topics intersection computation if the sum of the topics for both attendees is less than the maximum.

I don't know that optimization alone will be sufficient.